# How to make a collapsed tab item visible programmatically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, tabs, visibility, tabitem

how do i make a collapsed tab item visible programmatically in WPF?

I have created a xaml file with a tabcontrol with three tabs, the visibility property I have set succesively to Visible. Hidden and Collapsed.  Also I have two buttons one to set Tab 2 to visible and the other to set Tab 3 to visible.
In the code behind I have set up an event handler for each button.

The event handlers don't compile.

I would appreciate any suggestions . Thanks!

```
Here is my MainWindow.xaml

<Window x:Class="WPFTabItemVisibility.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Visibility="Visible" Content="Tab 1 Content goes here"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Tab 2 Content goes here"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Tab 3 Content goes here"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <Button Content="Make Tab 2 Visible" Margin="20" Height="30" Width="200" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Make Tab 3 Visible" Margin="20" Height="30" Width="200" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;    


namespace WPFTabItemVisibility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                TabIndex = 1;
                TabItem.VisibilityProperty = IsVisible;

            }

            private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                TabIndex = 2;
                TabItem.VisibilityProperty = IsVisible;
            }
        }
    }

Thank you!
```

Comment: Tabitem does not have a VisibilityProperty property.

Answer (score 2):

You can give name to the tabitem and set its visibility. Refer the below code.

```
 <TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Tab 1" Visibility="Visible" Content="Tab 1 Content goes here"></TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="Tab 2" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Tab 2 Content goes here"></TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="tab3" Header="Tab 3" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Tab 3 Content goes here"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tab2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tab3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in your XAML

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1"
                 Visibility="Visible"
                 Name="tab1"
                 Content="Tab 1 Content goes here"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2"
                 Visibility="Hidden"
                 Name="tab2"
                 Content="Tab 2 Content goes here"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3"
                 Name="tab3"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                 Content="Tab 3 Content goes here"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <Button Content="Make Tab 2 Visible"
            Margin="20"
            Height="30"
            Width="200"
            Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Content="Make Tab 3 Visible"
            Margin="20"
            Height="30"
            Width="200"
            Click="Button_Click_1" />
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind .cs File

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TabIndex = 1;
        //TabItem.VisibilityProperty = IsVisible;
        tab2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TabIndex = 2;
        //TabItem.VisibilityProperty = IsVisible;
        tab3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```